# Problems with outer_div

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that I have a page where I use a modal and inside of the modal I show a table with results from a DB, so I created a master-page where I manage the background and other things... the point here is that the outer_div class disable the background of the page.

I already tried it to take out but if I do it doesn't appear the table into the modal. What can I do?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h4 class="modal-title"  id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" >
                    <div class="form-row col-sm-12">
                        <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" id="q" placeholder="Buscar productos" onkeyup="load(1)" style="font-size: 9pt;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick="load(1)"style="font-size: 9pt;"><span class='fa fa-search' ></span> Buscar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br>
                <div id="loader" style="position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 55px;  width: 100%;display:none;"></div>
                    <div class="outer_div" ></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS code.

Comment: you know? the problem is that I use that class from boostrap I didn't write anything about css. But this is the code to fill up the table into modal

Comment: <div class="table-responsive" >
     <table class="table">

this is part of the code to fill up the table ... is it works to you?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. What do you mean by .outer_div is disabling the background? Bootstrap's modal includes a gray backdrop by default, do you mean that? You can remove it by including data-backdrop="false" on the .modal element.